# How to avoid the creation of the column called "Target Path"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list

Which types of lists can I create that DO NOT automatically create the required field column called "Target Path"? How can I avoid its creation in the beginning?

Comment: What's the **Internal Name** of "Target Path" column? Can you describe what kind of lists you have created that show column [Target Path], and is required? Using any custom content type?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this column automatically created for all lists possibly because it is attached to the content type **Item** (or **Document** for document libraries).

You may confirm by navigating to *Site Settings* > *Site Content Types* > **Item** under *List Content Types* and then check if the **Target Path** column is added to the content type.

If yes, remove it from the content type. Note that it won’t remove the existing Target Path columns in lists.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing - I can remove it from the content type, and make it a non-required field.  However, when I go to create a form using InfoPath, it seems that InfoPath automatically makes this a required field once again, no matter how many times I try to remove it.

Comment: @DanJ Do you see that column even after you remove the column from the content type, and create a new list afterwards? *Target Path* is a system default column indeed, but it is not set as required by default.

Comment: yes, I still see it then.

Comment: @DanJ Do you see this behavior in all sites in your environment? And what if you delete this column using PowerShell, referring to this doc: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/delete-site-column-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html?